# Interpolation of a dataframe with immediate data appearing before and after it - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

Let's say I've a dataframe like this -

```
ID  Weight Height
1   80.0   180.0
2   60.0   170.0
3   NaN    NaN
4   NaN    NaN
5   82.0   185.0
```

I want the dataframe to be transormed to -

```
ID  Weight  Height
1   80.0    180.0
2   60.0    170.0
3   71.0    177.5
4   76.5    181.25
5   82.0    185.0
```

It takes the average of the immediate data available before and after a NaN and updates the missing/NaN value accordingly.

Comment: Hello @Rithvik; welcome to SO. Have you been through [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I believe after you read it carefully, you will get more people to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Naguid, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use interpolation from the `pandas` library by using the following:

```
df['Weight'], df['Height'] = df.Weight.interpolate(), df.Height.interpolate()
```

Check the arguments on the documentation for the method of interpolation to tune this to your problem case: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html

Comment: Thanks, I found the `slinear` method to be the most useful for my case even though it doesn't give exactly what I'm looking for.